# Why am I not able to force the form element to expand to 957px?

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to force this form element to expand to 957px. Here is the page.
https://www.whiteribbonalliance.org/index.cfm/donate-usd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove this you will have a chance to expand it:

*style.css:57*:

```
#primary form {
    ...
    max-width: 504px;
}
```

[`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/max-width), as its name implies, tells the maximum width that the element can have.

I found it by simply using the [Chrome Inspector](http://www.threetipsaday.com/2008/12/debug-inspect-google-chrome-inspector/).